# How to do this workflow in sharepoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I have a customer has an office and asking for this workflow :
When a customer asking for a service, the reception's employee file a form then that form directly go to finance division . Then when the customer pay the fee , the finance's employee press a button then it goes to another employee depending on the type of task . Each stage (after finance division there are 4 stages)should not take more than 3 days . If it takes more than that the task should send an alert to the owner .

The question is : 
**Can that workflow applied in sharepoint , and what is the best practice to do this kind of workflow ?**

Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes. [See MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163986.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this workflow can be implemented... We can use SharePoint designer workflow for this activity. Although. you might need some custom task / forms.